# GetDirectories - Retrieve only a few folders from the Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

New to c# and ASP.net, I am working on retrieving Directories and have done so.

```
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListItem item;
            ListItem item
            string folderLocation = @"\\serv5007i\TeamCityDeploy\Trunk Production Build\Current\bin\Runtime";
            int startSize = folderLocation.Length+1;

            string[] fileNames = Directory.GetDirectories(folderLocation);
            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {

                item = new ListItem();
                item.Value = item.Text = "Add " + fileName.Substring(startSize);
                CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(item);
                CheckBoxList2.Items.Add(item);
                CheckBoxList3.Items.Add(item);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

So I have the output as the Directory of 15 or so folders. Is it possible to return only 10 and then 5 in another div.

So basically I have 15 folders being returned, but I need to have the bottom 5 under a different heading to the others. My apologies if I'm not being clear. Beginner!

Comment: You can use for loop or counter to limit it to 10 or 5.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, filter the directories by some convention, or simply ignore particular ones?  Can you give us more information.  Right now the example is too broad.

Comment: Use Linq (if you are new to C# you *have* to learn Linq!). To get the first 10 directories, you can use `var fileNames = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("").Take(10)`. To get directories 11 to 15, you use `Directory.EnumerateDirectories("").Skip(10).Take(5)`. I'm hoping that the code is pretty self-explanatory - Linq tends to make easy-to-read code :)

Comment: Sorry if the explanation is broad. 
The above returns my 15 Folders. (Eg: The heading is ABC)
I need to return the first ten so the heading ABC is above that. 
Then return 11-14 with the heading (DEF)

If that makes sense. Appreciate your patience :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the output, when you execute `Directory.GetDirectories` you'll receive a collection.  I believe in this instance, you'll receive a string array.  This can be manipulated however you want:

*Loop Example's:*

```
foreach(string directory in directories)
{
     // Enumerate over all items within the collection.
}
```

---

```
for(int index = 0; index < directories.Length; index++)
{
   // Will enumerate until index == directories
   // If you make index five, it would start at position six of the array.
   // since they're zero based.  But you can manipulate how you want.
}
```

---

```
do
{
     index++
     // Perform an action. Based on the while.
}

while(index != directories.Length);
```

---

```
while(index != directories)
{
     index++;
     // Perform action until equal.
}
```

The downfall to these approaches, are you're manipulating a integer for a starting position or ending position.  Which can create confusion in the code.  The other approach would be Linq, which similar to the above as far as iteration but will make the code a bit more expressive.

*Linq Example's:*

```
var filtered = directories.Take(10); // Take the first ten.
var filtered = directories.Skip(5); // Skip the first five.
var filtered = directories.Where(path => new DirectoryInfo(path).Name.Contains("Name")); // If directory names contain, return on that.
```

You could also do:

```
var filter = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)
                      .Where(directory => directory.Name.Contains("Sample"))
                      .Take(10);
```

So the initial line will automatically enumerate the directories within the provided path, you filter based on name, then take the first ten.

You can tackle this problem a lot of different ways, that is why narrowing it down would be more helpful.

> "Go not to the Elves for counsel, for they will say both no and yes."

---

**Update:**

A full Linq example would be one of these two approaches:

```
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
var filtered = directories.Skip(5);
```

Or you could do it in a single line.

```
var filtered = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).Skip(5).Take(5);
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, the LINQ examples, I'm unsure where I would put those lines. Is it in the foreach loop?

Comment: I have managed to get the 10 boxes, but the name of the folders are not appearing.

Comment: string[] fileNames = Directory.GetDirectories(folderLocation);
            for(int index = 10; index < fileNames.Length; index++)

Comment: @conye9980 You may need to dump the path into `DirectoryInfo`.

Comment: @conye9980 Linq is actually replacing the loop.  I'll update to show you.

Comment: Ah I see now. Thanks